# Deriving number of unique ID counts from a data frame and creating new columns for counts and values

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe reshape/counting problem. Consider the following data frame with a column of non-unique IDs and a value column (could be uniques but doesn't have to be):

```
id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4)
value_df<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
df<-data.frame(id,value_df)

  df
   id value_df
1   1        A
2   1        B
3   1        C
4   2        D
5   2        E
6   3        F
7   4        G
8   4        H
9   4        I
10  4        J
```

What I am after is to create a dataframe where the first column contains the unique id's, the second the counts of these and the rest n columns the values for each id, like this:

```
  df_counts_reshape
  id number_id value_df_1 value_df_2 value_df_3 value_df_4
1  1         3          A          B          C          N
2  2         2          D          E         <NA>       <NA>
3  3         1          F         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4  4         4          G          I          J          K
```

Using the plyr-package deriving the counts are easy, like this

```
count(df,"id")
```

but then my problem starts. To get the rest of the dataframe I have tried *melt* and *dcast* from the reshape2-package.

```
df_melted<-melt(df,id.vars =c("id"), measure.vars = c("value_df"))
df_cast<-dcast(df_melted,id~value)
```

This, however, results in the following output:

```
   df_cast
  id    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
1  1    A    B    C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  2 <NA> <NA> <NA>    D    E <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    G    H    I    J
```

This output has many more "value" columns than what I wished for but I cannot find and easy way to simplify it to the output I want above. I was also thinking that the last step to get the number_id in would be with rbind.

Needless to say my actual dataframes contain many thousands of row which make the current melt/dcast output very clumsy with thousands of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df<-data.frame(id,value_df)
df$num <- ave(as.character(df$value_df), df$id, FUN = seq_along)
df = reshape(df,idvar = "id",direction = "wide",timevar = "num" )
```

Result:

```
> df
  id value_df.1 value_df.2 value_df.3 value_df.4
1  1          A          B          C       <NA>
4  2          D          E       <NA>       <NA>
6  3          F       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
7  4          G          H          I          J
```

What this does is it adds a numeric column that sequences 1:n for each group of ids. Then it uses those values as the new column names

Comment: Thanks, I will have to play around a little bit but it is a very good start. It turns out that my df$id can be NA depsite a value in the value_df column which seems to complicate matter for my large datasets.